# Gating Sequence for MOSFET in Simulink for a Resistive load Microinverter

Tags: power-electronics, simulink

I am trying to design a simple Micro inverter, using a solar cell and four MOSFET's with a resistive load.

How do i get a phasing sequence for the MOSFET's in the following circuit :-

[image]

Circuit : -

- Solar cell produces a DC output using 25 Degree Centigrade as temperature, with 1000 Irradiance
- The DC produced is then supplied to MOSFET's, parallel branches of two each

How do i design the Gating sequence of these in simulink, using PWM?? Or is there any other way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is always a good place to start.

From sources place a repeating sequence and configure it as a triangle wave... Peak of 1, freq 10k.

Also as a sinus source. Peak of 1, freq of 50Hz

Add a compare block (under discrete) and send the sine wave to input 1 and the triangle to input 2.

Consider the numbering of the MOSFETS

```
1 3
4 2
```

Send the outout of the compare block to MOSFETs 1 & 2.  Add a logic inverter and send the inverted signal to 3 & 4

This is a simple open loop sinus generator. Once this is working, more complicated strategies can be used